# Two-handed cribbage

Tags: cribbage, scoring

This evening, after contributing to the crib, I held three 5s and the Jack of the 5 that was turned by my opponent.

So, what did my hand score, with the four fives and the Jack of the knobs, after the pegging?

Answer (score 3):

This particular hand is the famous "29 hand" which is the highest scoring cribbage hand.  In fact, you can even get cribbage scoring boards with this design.

[image]

The scoring breakdown for this hand is as follows:

- 8 fifteens for 16

  - 4 fifteens made of a 5 and the J
  - 4 fifteens made of 3 fives (omit each of the 5's once)
- 6 pairs for 28 ([4 choose 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%20choose%202) ways to pair the 5's)
- Knobs

The hand scores `8*2 + 6*2 + 1 = 29`